# Calculate the sum of series with square roots

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Calculate the sum of the following series using partial sums:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+1}} $$

I rationalized the upper part of the fraction but I got lost. Could you please help me showing the steps of the how to transform the fraction into a partial sum? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, this is a telescoping series. If you struggle with the details you might find this helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3250988/calculation-of-a-series-using-series-definition/3251011#3251011

Answer (score 7):

**HINT:**$$\frac{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much but how can I get there. Did you multiplied the fraction by $\frac{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1} + \sqrt{n}}$ ?

Comment: No, you don't have to make this too complicated. Just write it as $\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+1}} - \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+1}}$.

Comment: Oh, I completely forgot about that! Thanks a lot !!!!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck!